# SQL Insert data from 2 table to new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to combine 2 table into 1 table as example below

Table1

```
    100
    200
    300
```

Table2

```
    A     B     C
    D     E     F
    G     H     I
```

OutputTable

```
   100   A     B     C
   100   D     E     F
   100   G     H     I
   200   A     B     C
   200   D     E     F
   200   G     H     I
   300   A     B     C
   300   D     E     F
   300   G     H     I
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Cross Join` which will create a `Cartesian product` of two tables

```
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM   table1 a
       CROSS JOIN table2 b
```

or Use `Cross Apply`

```
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM   table1 a
       CROSS Apply table2 b
```

Answer (score 3):

If you already have the new table then:

```
insert into new_table (field1,field2,field3,field4)
select 
     a.field1
     ,b.field2
     ,b.field3
     ,b.field4
from a
cross join b
```

If you do not have the table:

```
select 
    a.field1
    ,b.field2
    ,b.field3
    ,b.field4
into new_table
from a
cross join b
```